# How to attach debugger in VSCode to Dockerized Yarn Berry (pnp) process while ignoring package errors?

Tags: visual-studio-code, yarnpkg-v2

I'm using the following `launch.json` to debug my container:

```json
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach",
      "request": "attach",
      "type": "node",
      "restart": true,
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
      "remoteRoot": "/home/node/dist",
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/dist",
      "skipFiles": [
        // Ignore node_modules folder when debugging.
        "${workspaceFolder}/.yarn/**",
        // Ignore NodeJS when debugging.
        "<node_internals>/**/*.js"
      ],
      "outFiles": ["${workspaceFolder}/dist/**/**.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm running a NestJS application (it's compiling TypeScript and running using NodeJS). My  `package.json` script is `nest start --debug 0.0.0.0:9229 --watch`.

The debugger attaches successfully and I get to debug normally, but when I enable exception breakpoints, it catches exceptions within the packages (yarn cache but node-modules, essentially). I wish to skip these. Without PnP, it works fine (simply skip node internals and node modules), but with PnP, I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: found any solution? :) I am having the same issue

Comment: @tHeSiD No honestly I gave up. Still can't find a solution. Update with an answer if you find the solution please!

Comment: can you try `"**/.yarn/**",` and `**/node_modules/**` in skip files along with your other yarn exclusions? This seemed to work for me, however I am not using nextjs